# Symfony bundle - REST API Two types of authentication

Tags: php, api, symfony4

This is an opinion request.
I'm developing a Symfony4 bundle that will interact with a REST API of an SMS service.
This service has two ways to authenticate:

1. Getting a Session Id that expires in 5 minutes if no request is sent
2. Getting a Token always valid

Both are retrieved by providing username and password to the authentication method, then they will be used in each curl header request.

My question is: should i provide both types of authentication in my bundle or should i choose just one?

If both will be available, as my bundle will provide a *service* to interact with the SMS application, should i add the type of authentication to use in the configuration?

```
mysms_bundle:
  usernam: myuser
  password: mypass
  auth_type: token
  # You can also use session
  # auth_type: session
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably allow both types of authentication and let the user to choose which is the preferred auth method if both are available.
Anyway you should fallback to the other auth method if the first fails.

And default that preference to the more secure one (or the one preferred or suggested by the external service docs).

Comment: So the configuration proposed could be ok? Default value of `auth_type` will be "token" and the user will be able to change it. I think that the authorization fallback mechanism it's not a good idea unless you let the user opt for that solution with a  `fallback_auth: true` config variable. It can be useful having an expiring session even if it's renewed every api call. What dou you think?

Comment: Yes, right. An opt-in (or an opt-out) for the fallback is a good idea